# Can we have Multiple Roles in Single UserPool in AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am working on a Project and in there I have used AWS Cognito for basic Authentication for My Web Application; In this web Application I am providing multiple role-based Authentication (Like Super User, User, Admin, Super Admin) and for that right now I have created different Userpools for each. Is there another way to achieve the same functionality? like I can use single Userpool and still can achieve Role-based Authentication. Also, which one is the Appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup different groups in the same Cognito User Pool.
In your case Super User, Admin and Super Admin. Then assign your users to the group that they belong to. In your backend code you will then need to check what group the user is in by looking up the group that the user belong to.

See this link for more details: [cognito-user-pools-user-groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-user-groups.html)